# SSRS 2008 Draw line chart on top of bar chart using different sum from same dataset

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

The dataset has 3 columns:

`Year, Gross, Location`

I'm trying to create a chart that shows the current year's Gross with the bars and the prior year's Gross with the line (both by Location).

Ideally, the chart would look similar to the image below. I can change my query to include the the prior year's gross in an additional column and get the desired result, but I was hoping there was a way to do handle this using my existing dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with simple Categories groupings, because the Groups for Location - A - This Year do not intersects with Location - B - Next year.